# How can i print just a single column from a two dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this program im writing and i have to print just one column of a two dimensional array, not both.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sjf.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < sjf[i].length; j++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%5d%4s   ", sjf[i][j], "|");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: So need value of specific column ?? or any column??

Comment: requirement is not very clear... my guess... use a variable to scanf number of column, say theColumn and if the value i==theColumn printf ...

Comment: @AshutoshNigam **Java**

Comment: @m0skit0 System.out.scanf in case of java :)

Comment: Which column you want to print then?

Comment: @AshutoshNigam There's no such thing in Java.

Comment: Do not vandalize your questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you want to print the fifth column:

```
int column = 5;
for (int[] row : sjf) {
       System.out.printf("%5d%4s   ", row[column], "|");
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it that what you need:

```
int j = <column_nr>;
for (int i = 0; i < sjf.length; i++)
        {
                System.out.printf("%5d%4s   ", sjf[i][j], "|");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use the inner `for` loop.

```
int colToPrint = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < sjf.length; i++)
{
    System.out.printf("%5d%4s   ", sjf[i][colToPrint], "|");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here I've printed the second column i.e with index 1.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?
given the array sjf as an example
            int sjf[][]={{1, 3, 5}, {5, 7, 7}};

```
        for(int i = 0; i < sjf.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < sjf[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%5d%4s   \n", sjf[i][j], "|");
            }
            //System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
```

OUTPUT

```
1   |   
3   |   
5   |   
5   |   
7   |   
7   |
```

Comment: you printed out all of the data

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < sjf.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < sjf[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(j==1)//in case second column is printed out
               System.out.printf("%5d%4s   ", sjf[i][j], "|");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

used an advanced for loop:

```
    // local variable to hold the column we wish to print       
    int colToPrint = 2;
    for (int row : sjf[colToPrint-1]) {
        System.out.printf("%5d%4s%n", row, "|");
    }
```