# Printing a Specific Column in a 2D Java Array

Tags: java

I have accessor method, where a user submits a specific column from a 2D array that they want printed out. However, I am having trouble printing out the specific column.

For example:

```
public array[] column(int col)
{ 

}
```

And the 2D array is something like this:

```
5 5 5 5 5 0
8 5 2 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 1 5
```

So if somebody selects col = 3, it should print (5,5,5)

Comment: The method signature should probably be something like `public void printColumn(int[][] array)`

Comment: Then to print the third column (by rank), you would iterate over `array[i][2]`, varying `i` to cover all rows in the third column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i print just a single column from a two dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306668/how-can-i-print-just-a-single-column-from-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1):

**you should know no of rows in the array
you need to iterate through rows and the column value should be fixed**

```
int noOfRows, int noOFColmuns;

public void printColumn(int[][] arr, int col){
     for(int i = 0 ; i < noOfRows; i++){
     System.out.println(arr[i][col]);
}
```