# How to print values from specific column

Tags: java

so im trying to figure out how can i print a specific column from a given array, and im completely stuck.
ive manage to print the entire matrix but didnt manage to do it on a specific column.

this is for school

```
public class ex_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] arr = {{-1, -1, 1, 2, 3, -1},
                {-1, 4, 5, 1, -1, -1},
                {-1, -1, 6, 5, 4, 3},
                {-1, 2, 5, 3},
                {1, 2, 1}};

        getNumFromCol(arr, 1);
    }

    public static int getNumFromCol(int[][] mat, int col) {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
                if (mat[i][j] != -1) {
                    temp = mat[col][j];
                }
            }
            System.out.print(temp);
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

422

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing a Specific Column in a 2D Java Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047043/printing-a-specific-column-in-a-2d-java-array)

Comment: And another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306668/how-can-i-print-just-a-single-column-from-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score -1):

When accessing a 2D array `matrix` you need to give `matrix[i][j]` where `i` is the row number and `j` is the column number.

So if you want to print a certain column `col`, you need to print the item at the position `col` for each row in your matrix. It will look like this:

```
public static void printColumn(int[][] matrix, int col) {
    for (int[] row: matrix) {
        System.out.println(row[col]);
    }
}
```

## Note

If you want a *pretty* format for your column, you can use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) to build the output step by step. For example if you want column formatted like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, it will look like this

```
public static void printColumn(int[][] matrix, int col) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("[ ");

    for (int[] row: matrix) {
        sb.append(row[col]).append(' ');
    }

    sb.append(']');

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: [Why are you booing me? I'm right](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/why-are-you-booing-me-im-right)

Answer (score -1):

Well first of all you don't need to do nested loops. If you want to iterate on the whole matrix then you need to nest the loops - one for X and one for Y but since you already know the column then one loop will be enough.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < mat[col].length; j++) {
        temp = mat[col][j];
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
```